# jmeter Only send request with one number generated by __Random()

Tags: jmeter

Here are Jmeter script structure:

`Test Plan 
+ User Defined Variables
+ - votes_id: ${__P(votes_id,${__Random(11,14)})}
+ ...
+ Thread Group
+ + Throughput Controller1
+ + + Http Request1
+ + Throughput Controller2
+ + + Http Request2
+ + Throughput Controller3
+ + + Http Request3
+ + + Http Request4
+ + + - paramater1:${votes_id}`

**Issue: http request only send with the same num.**

when set paramater1:${__Random(11,14)}, it works with random number from 11 to 14.

Note: I have also try components CSV Data Set Config. when I disable Throughput Controller1, Throughput Controller2, Http Request4 works with multi number.

**How can I use CSV Data Set Config to send request parameter with random number?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per [Where can functions and variables be used?](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#where) chapter:

   > Functions and variables can be written into any field of any test component
2. [As per What can functions do](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do)

   > Functions are shared between threads. Each occurrence of a function call in a test plan is handled by a separate function instance.

So you basically don't need to define a variable, you can use [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function directly in the HTTP Request parameter section

```
Test Plan 
+ ...
+ Thread Group
+ + Throughput Controller1
+ + + Http Request1
+ + Throughput Controller2
+ + + Http Request2
+ + Throughput Controller3
+ + + Http Request3
+ + + Http Request4
+ + + - paramater1:${__P(votes_id,${__Random(11,14)})}
```

This way the function will be evaluated individually by each thread hence you will get a new value each time the function will be called.

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: It works well! Note that **Generating unique random values at run-time is expensive in terms of CPU and memory, so just create the data in advance of the test**, so I try replace __Random() function with CSV Data Set Config and fail.. Details: input a.csv with 11\n12\n13\n14, then the request parameter will only contain 13. when I disable Throughput Controller1 and Throughput Controller2, it send request with all number in a.csv

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) for other then initial values:

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they
>   are - are processed at the start.
>
> UDVs should not be used with functions that generate different results
>   each time they are called. Only the result of the first function call
>   will be saved in the variable. However, UDVs can be used with
>   functions such as __P()
>
> For defining variables during a test run, see User Parameters. UDVs
>   are processed in the order they appear in the Plan, from top to
>   bottom.

Use[User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) and put it as Pre processor child of HTTP request. It'll be called every time.